# Behringer xenix 1202fx: delay audio output

Tags: behringer, delay

We have a Behringer xenix 1202FX audio mixer, and we need to delay the audio output two or three frames.  The video signal has a slight delay due to signal processing, but audio from the mixer does not, so there is no lip-synch.

With the available effects both delayed audio and original audio can be heard.  Is there a way to only output the delayed audio?

Comment: Is this analog video and audio? I'm wondering why you are not shifting the audio in the non-linear software editor of choice unless you are editing with decks.

Answer (score 3):

Usually a "delay" effect mixes the original and the delayed signal.  As an audio effect, this is often desirable.  Usually there is a control called "wet/dry mix" which is the level of the delayed signal relative to the original signal.  At 100% wet, only the delayed signal is heard.

Delay effects sometimes have a parameter called "feedback" which is the amount that the delayed signal is fed back into the input of the delay, creating a repeating echo effect.

If you have access to these controls on the 1202FX's effects section, set wet/dry to 100% wet, and feedback to 0.  Set the delay time to match the delay on your video.

If you don't have access to any parameters, and can only use precanned presets, I'd say bypass the effects section entirely, and get a hardware delay effect of some kind that you can put after your audio signal.  You can either put it in between the audio source and the mixer, or after the mixer.  The above settings apply here as well.